# How can I get a Mudkip?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In Pokemon Black & White 2 (3DS), can anyone give me advice on how to obtain / find a Mudkip, or if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the [Poké Transfer](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Transfer) on Route 15 to transfer one from a previous Generation IV game (e.g., HeartGold, SoulSilver).

Otherwise, you'll just need to find someone to trade with.

There was a [Mudkip](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_Global_Link_promotions/Pok%C3%A9mon#Mudkip) offered as a promo for the Japanese B/W version, but that has since been unavailable.